# Can we access the emailids from the contactlist from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, email, contacts

Can we access all the email IDs for each contact from the iPhone contactlist through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the individual email ids by given code...

```
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people  = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSString *contactName = lblTitle.text;
    for(int i = 0;i<ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
        NSString *strEmail = [arContactData valueForKey:@"Email"];
        NSMutableArray *arEmailList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        for(CFIndex idx = 0; idx < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); idx++)
        {
            CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, idx);
            NSString *strLbl = (NSString*)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex (emails, idx));
            NSDictionary *dicTemp = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:strEmail,@"value", strLbl,@"label", nil];  
            [arEmailList addObject:dicTemp];        
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is arContactData in the above code? Also I get a cast error in this line :  
`NSString *strLbl = (NSString*)ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex (emails, idx));`

Comment: arContactData is a MutableArray. And I have checked it @ my end and I haven't found any cast error as you found.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use the ABAdressBook class:

> ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
>   NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

Now you have all contacts in the allPeople array, then just get the email by key.