# custom ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, addressbook, abpeoplepickerview

Is there any way that I can customize ABPeoplePickerNavController data source?
I mean instead of taking members from phone's addressBook, I need it to take data from array for example in my application.
I will get list of members from server and I want to display them in ABPeoplePickerNavCont.

If it is not possible, is there any custom ABPeoplePicker. Or will I have to create it all over from ground?

Thank you.

Comment: just go through this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930019/can-we-access-the-emailids-from-the-contactlist-from-iphone

Answer (score 3):

[Apple's ABPeoplePickerNavigationController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that you can set an ABAddressBookRef ("addressBook" is a property of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController) from which the list of contacts is obtained. So you just need to provide an ABAddressBookRef that supplies the list of contacts you want to use.